# Is it possible in JS to assign in one line destructured object keys to another object?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

My question is really simple but I have not been able to find an answer to this.

Currently I have this :

```
const {email, firstname, lastname, isAdmin} = decodeToken(token);
const user = {email, firstname, lastname, isAdmin};
```

I'm looking for a way to shorten this chunk of code into a single line. I tried different combinations but none worked.

Comment: 1. Create a function. 2. Reuse it. 3. Done - it's short and simple anywhere you use it.\

Comment: What you really want is to **not** destructure. Simply don't use destructuring

Comment: If you're using lodash, `_.pick(decodeToken(token), ['email', 'firstname', 'lastname', 'isAdmin'])` will do the trick.

Comment: You cannot avoid typing the variable names twice, without using helper functions. If the "*problem*" is the two lines, although i cannot see why that would be, you can use `const {email, firstname, lastname, isAdmin, user={email, firstname, lastname, isAdmin}} = decodeToken();` but i post this only as a technical solution. Not one that should be really used. The two lines you have are just fine and clear to understand.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can simply write:

```
const user = {email, firstname, lastname, isAdmin} = decodeToken(token);
```

So you can have the `user` object and the destructured fields accessible as variables in the scope.

> **UPDATE**
>
> This code as to be considered careful as @VLAZ pointed out in the comment, the destructured variables now are global.
> You can still avvoid this but you cannot have it in a single line as you requested:

```
let email, firstname, lastname, isAdmin;
const user = {email, firstname, lastname, isAdmin} = decodeToken(token);
```

If you don't need the destructured fields you can shorten even more:

```
const user = decodeToken(token);
```

Comment: "*I think you can simply write:*" it would also make `email`, `firstname`, `lastname`, and `isAdmin` implicit globals.

Comment: So your updated code, is just like the OP. Two lines, you just moved the `decodeToken` to the second line.

Comment: Except for the explanation.

Comment: @MarioSantini sorry if it sounded aggressive. I was just pointing out that that snippet was identical to the OP code.